# Prove that $f$ and $g$ are the same function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions so that for any rational number $r$, $f(r) = g(r)$. Prove that $f$ and $g$ are the same function.

I need some hints to get started on this question. Thanks.

Comment: **Hint** : $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Oliver Your hint is useless.

Comment: @user115295 I disagree: it is a standard result that two continuous functions which agree on a dense set are equal, and in fact this is the heart of the question.

Comment: @Alex Your disagreement isn't the issue here. I asked a question and if I don't find the comments helpful or don't understand them clearly then I can obviously voice my opinion for my purpose of solving the question. So stay out of it and mind your own business.

Comment: @user115295 I think you're misinterpreting the flag "Not Constructive". A comment is "Not Constructive" if it would not be useful to any user looking at the question, not if it is not useful to the asker. This is in line with the general StackExchange policy to focus on anyone reading a question, not just the asker. And for the record, my disagreement is the issue and it is my business, since as a moderator it is my job to accept or decline flags on comments, such as your flag on Oliver's comment, which I declined for the reasons I gave.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. We are told that $h(r)=0$ for every rational $r$. Note that $h(x)$ is continuous. Can you conclude that $h(x)=0$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $h$ be infinitesimally small.

**Hint :** $f(x+h) = g(x+h)$ (why? Think)